# Jquery form validation: explanatory paragraph not showing

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am having trouble with form validation using JQuery.

My code should show a paragraph that explains the required fields at the top of the page when the page loads. This paragraph isn't showing up.

This is my complete file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="form_jquery.aspx.cs"
Inherits="form_jquery" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
            <link rel="Stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
            />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var requiredFlag = ' * ';
                    var requiredKey = $('input.required:first').next('span').text();
                    requiredKey = requiredFlag + requiredKey.replace(/^\((.+)\)$/, "$1");
                    var conditionalFlag = ' ** ';
                    var conditionalKey = $('input.conditional:first').next('span').text();
                    conditionalKey = conditionalFlag + conditionalKey.replace(/\((.+)\)/, "$1");
                    $('form :input').filter('.required').next('span').text(requiredFlag).end().prev('label').addClass('req-label');
                    $('form :input').filter('.conditional').next('span').text(conditionalFlag);
                    $('<p></p>').addClass('field-keys').append(requiredKey + '<br />').append(conditionalKey).insertBefore('#contact');
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Info</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                                <input class="required" type="text" name="first-name"
                                id="first-name" />
                                <span>(required)</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                                <input class="required" type="text" name="last-name"
                                id="last-name" />
                                <span>(required)</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>How would you like to be contacted? (choose at least one method)
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="by-email">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="by-contact-type" value="E-mail" id="by-email"
                                            />by E-Mail</label>
                                        <input class="conditional" type="text" name="email" id="email"
                                        />
                                        <span>(required when corresponding checkbox checked)</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="by-phone">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="by- contact-type" value="Phone" id="by-phone"
                                            />by Phone</label>
                                        <input class="conditional" type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
                                        />
                                        <span>(required when corresponding checkbox checked)</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label for="by-fax">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="by- contact-type" value="Fax" id="by-fax"
                                            />by Fax</label>
                                        <input class="conditional" type="text" name="fax" id="fax"
                                        />
                                        <span>(required when corresponding checkbox checked)</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? And why are you using jQuery 1.6.2 when the current stable version is 1.8.0? And third, why are you rolling your own validation, when validate (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is such an excellent plugin?

Comment: One thing to do before dumping your page, make it easy to read, use a tool like http://jsbeautifier.org the source makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: @Mark, nice link! I'm adding it to my toolbox

Comment: @dnagirl 
i am learning jquery so i want to do it as it is.The error is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AmritPal: I understand that you don't see one of your paragraphs. That's the result, not the error. I'm asking if there is an actual javascript error as opposed to just an unexpected result.

Comment: how are you really planning to validate this page?where is the event to validate

Comment: @Utkarsh
A Javascript code at page load will do it.I must show a paragraph at the top of page when it loads which tells about required field.

Comment: I started to edit your post to remove ***everything*** that had nothing to do with your question (hint: doctype, ul, body, etc). And then I saw the answer. I leave it to you to do it, so that you can learn how to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
.insertBefore('#contact')
```

but I don't see any element with an `id="contact"` on your page. Is something missing? Otherwise, you need to supply a valid selector for jQuery to target.

Also, and you didn't tag this in your question, but that top line of yours leads me to assume you're doing WebForms development. Be aware that any markup with a `runat="server"` will NOT have the `id` you typed into your markup (or the designer).